# Placing ads in an UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, mopub, twitter-fabric

I'm currently developing an app that requires ads placed within the cells or "tiles" of a grid. The grid is created using a view controller with an UICollectionView. It has two cells going across and is scrollable vertically. The fabric SDK I'm using gives users the option to implement mopub ads within apps and I would like these ads to appear randomly within the grid. Any suggestions? The app is also a basic RSS feed I'm experimenting with.

Comment: Have you tried MoPub native ads with MPTableViewAdPlacer?...https://fabric.io/kits/ios/mopub/features

Comment: @sanman thanks. I did a little more digging and found TONS of resources surrounding MPTableViewAdPlacer. Everything is working smooth so far so thanks a million